# EE3 category select custom field

Tags: categories, custom-fields

Is there an EE3 custom field out there somewhere that allows selecting one or more categories, like this EE2 addon by Wes Baker: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-category-select

Comment: The default category selection per entry isn't sufficient?

Comment: No, it has to be a custom field so it can be used in other add-ons.

Comment: Can u expand on your initial question as you comment makes it appear that you want categories but won't be using the syntax for traditional category tags inside an entry.

Comment: I added a link to an EE2 addon that does exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: It appears you can grab the source code or request a fork on GitHub and you can make it EE3 compatible here: https://github.com/wesbaker/category_select.ee2_addon/blob/master/third_party/wb_category_select/ft.wb_category_select.php

Comment: I realise that but I do not have any php or other backend coding experience.